# What is the right way to implement a callback/listener pattern?

Tags: flutter, dart

Sorry if this is a novice question. I have the following repo file:

```
class TwitterRepo {

   final TwitterRepoCallback _callback;

   TwitterRepo(this._callback){
        // do stuff
   }

}

abstract class TwitterRepoCallback{

    void onEvent();

}
```

In my UI file I have the following:

```
class TweetList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _TweetListState();
  }

}

class _TweetListState extends State<TweetList> implements TwitterRepoCallback {

  final TwitterRepo _twitterRepo = TwitterRepo(this);

  // other stuff like initState, build and onEvent

}
```

There is an error on

```
final TwitterRepo _twitterRepo = TwitterRepo(this);
```

where I use "this", *Invalid reference to 'this' expression*.

I'm at a loss on how to pass in my callback to receive events.

Comment: In my opinion, Must override onEvent method in TweetListState class.

Comment: I do override it. I omitted that from this example to keep it simple. See the comments

Comment: I have one question. Do you need abstract callback method?

Comment: I don't know! I just started learning flutter/dart. Is there another approach you would recommend?

Comment: I'm trying to get the gist of what you're aiming to do. It seems like you're trying to grab some information off a network connection, use that information and inject it into your UI? Does that about sum it up?

Comment: Yes Adrian, onEvent will let my listview know it has new data to render.

Comment: I don't know if that's the approach I'd take for something like that. I would probably set up some kind of Stream, or a Provider that listens in for new data. Provider is essentially a sugar coated version of an InheritedWidget. You could setup your network listener within the parent InheritedWidget then keep its data there in a variable and use notifyListeners() to update the Consumers down the widget tree.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
class ParentPageState extends State<ParentPage> implement Callback{
   ...
   @override
   void callback(){
     ...
   }

   @override
   void callback1(String str){
      ....
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
     return Scaffold(
        body : Container(
          child : ChildPage(callback : this.callback, callback1 : this.callback1)
        )
     );
   }
}
```

And ChildPage

```
import .....
//Main Point
typedef Callback = void Function();
typedef Callback1 = void Function(String str);
class ChildPage extends StatelessWidget{
   final Callback _callback;
   final Callback1 _callback1;
   ChildPage({Callback callback, Callback1 callback1}): _callback : callback, _callback1 : callback1;
   .....

   @override 
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
      return Container(
          child : InkWell(
             onPressed : (){
                this._callback();
                this._callback1("test");
             },
             child : ....
          )
      );
   }
```

This is may have issue. The main point is "typedef"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the callback to notify the UI to render some new data, you may want to use `Future` or `Stream`. Anyway, the question is how to implement a callback/listener so here I give you some examples:

---

You can't declare a variable using `this`, you could initialize the variable on the constructor

```
_TweetListState() {
  _twitterRepo = TwitterRepo(this);
}
```

or inside `initState()`

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _twitterRepo = TwitterRepo(this);
}
```

---

A better way to do this would be:

```
final TwitterRepo _twitterRepo = TwitterRepo();

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _twitterRepo.listen(this);
}
```

And the `listen` method implemented on `TwitterRepo` would set the callback

---

You could also use `VoidCallback` instead of `TwitterRepoCallback`:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _twitterRepo.listen(() {
    // Do stuff
  });
}
```

Or a callback function using `Function(String a, int b)` instead of `TwitterRepoCallback`

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _twitterRepo.listen((a, b) {
    // Do stuff
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you but what if I want _twitterRepo to be a final variable?

Comment: If you want to make it final then declare it as a final variable but dont set it. Then in your _TweetListState class you can create it in the constructor and not during the initState method. _TweetListState() : _twitterRepo = TwitterRepo(this);

Comment: Do note that in order to call it in the constructor the TwitterRepo class must be allowed to be made const. So all of its properties must be final as well.

Comment: You can't do that neither, you'll get the same error. One way to declare _twitterRepo as final could be to change the TwitterRepo constructor to not receive the callback and set the callback later, but that will need to make the callback not final inside TwitterRepo

Comment: In either case, I don't think this pattern is the best approach given things like ValueNotifiers, ChangeNotifiers, Streams, and other ways to update UI on data changes. I see callbacks as a way to update UI based off of simple user interaction - not gestures, but like going back pages. Also, if he wants to update the UI off of his callback he needs to hook it up so that when it's fired it calls the super.setState((){}) function. Otherwise nothing would happen upon onEvent.

Comment: I agree with Adrian, anyway I updated the answer with an example of how to use the callback since that's the question

Answer (score 0):

I probably wouldn't use callbacks for this type of need. Instead I'd use some kind of InheritedWidget like system to grab data and propagate it down the widget tree. I know you just started, but a great tool is the [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package. To do what you're trying to do here it'd look something like this:

```
class TwitterRepo extends ChangeNotifier{
  //construct Repo
  TwitterRepo(){
     _setupNetworkListener();
  }

  List<Data> data = [];

  //set up the way to listen to and get data here then add it to your list, 
  //finally notify your listeners of the data changes
  _setupNetworkListener()async{
    var _data = await gettingInfo();
    data.addAll(_data);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}


class TwitterRepoUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TwitterRepoUIState createState() => _TwitterRepoUIState();
}

class _TwitterRepoUIState extends State<TwitterRepoUI> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<TwitterRepo>(
      builder: (context)=> TwitterRepo(),
      child: Consumer<TwitterRepo>(
        builder: (context, model, child){

          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: model.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return Center(
                child: Text(index.toString()),
              );
            });

        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```